# Android 11 MediaStyle Notification crash

Tags: android, notifications

I'm using a MediaStyle Notification in my app.  Its been working fine until Android 11.  On Android 11 it crashes the Android UI (not just the app, it takes down Android's UI).

There are no error in logcat on the app, but there are errors from Android itself.

```
    fun buildNotificationAsync(sessionToken: MediaSessionCompat.Token): Deferred<Notification> = GlobalScope.async {
    if (shouldCreateNowPlayingChannel()) {
        createNowPlayingChannel()
    }

    val controller = MediaControllerCompat(context, sessionToken)
    val description = controller.metadata.description
    val playbackState = controller.playbackState

    val builder = NotificationCompat.Builder(context, NOW_PLAYING_CHANNEL)

    // Only add actions for skip back, play/pause, skip forward, based on what's enabled.
    var playPauseIndex = 0
    if (playbackState.isSkipToPreviousEnabled) {
        builder.addAction(skipToPreviousAction)
        ++playPauseIndex
    }
    if (playbackState.isRewindEnabled) {
        builder.addAction(rewindAction)
        ++playPauseIndex
    }

    if (playbackState.isPlaying) {
        builder.addAction(pauseAction)
    } else if (playbackState.isPlayEnabled) {
        builder.addAction(playAction)
    }
    if (playbackState.isFastForwardEnabled) {
        builder.addAction(fastForwardAction)
    }
    if (playbackState.isSkipToNextEnabled) {
        builder.addAction(skipToNextAction)
    }
    val isHuaweiLollipop = (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT == Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP_MR1 ||
        Build.VERSION.SDK_INT == Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) &&
        Build.MANUFACTURER.toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault()).contains("huawei")

    if (!isHuaweiLollipop) {
        val mediaStyle = MediaStyle()
                .setCancelButtonIntent(stopPendingIntent)
                .setMediaSession(sessionToken)
                .setShowActionsInCompactView(playPauseIndex)
                .setShowCancelButton(true)

        builder.setStyle(mediaStyle)
    }

    description.iconUri?.let { uri ->
        val largeIcon = CoverCache.getInstance().fetchLargeIfNecessary(context, uri)
        largeIcon?.let { icon -> builder.setLargeIcon(icon) }
    }

    return@async builder.setContentIntent(controller.sessionActivity)
            .setContentText(description.subtitle)
            .setContentTitle(description.title)
            .setDeleteIntent(stopPendingIntent)
            .setOnlyAlertOnce(true)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_stat)
            .setVisibility(NotificationCompat.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC)
            .build()
}
```

I see this exception that I *think* is related:

```
         AndroidRuntime  E  FATAL EXCEPTION: SysUiBg
                     E  Process: com.android.systemui, PID: 26311
                     E  java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: opening provider androidx.core.content.FileProvider from ProcessRecord{410d665 26311:com.android.systemui/u0a141} (pid=26311, uid=10141) that is not exported from UID 10151
                     E      at android.os.Parcel.createExceptionOrNull(Parcel.java:2373)
                     E      at android.os.Parcel.createException(Parcel.java:2357)
                     E      at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:2340)
                     E      at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:2282)
                     E      at android.app.IActivityManager$Stub$Proxy.getContentProvider(IActivityManager.java:5702)
                     E      at android.app.ActivityThread.acquireProvider(ActivityThread.java:6813)
                     E      at android.app.ContextImpl$ApplicationContentResolver.acquireUnstableProvider(ContextImpl.java:2930)
                     E      at android.content.ContentResolver.acquireUnstableProvider(ContentResolver.java:2481)
                     E      at android.content.ContentResolver.openTypedAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:1967)
                     E      at android.content.ContentResolver.openTypedAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:1921)
                     E      at android.graphics.ImageDecoder$ContentResolverSource.createImageDecoder(ImageDecoder.java:274)
                     E      at android.graphics.ImageDecoder.decodeBitmapImpl(ImageDecoder.java:1862)
                     E      at android.graphics.ImageDecoder.decodeBitmap(ImageDecoder.java:1855)
                     E      at com.android.systemui.media.MediaDataManager.loadBitmapFromUri(MediaDataManager.kt:462)
                     E      at com.android.systemui.media.MediaDataManager.loadBitmapFromUri(MediaDataManager.kt:433)
                     E      at com.android.systemui.media.MediaDataManager.loadMediaDataInBg(MediaDataManager.kt:331)
                     E      at com.android.systemui.media.MediaDataManager.access$loadMediaDataInBg(MediaDataManager.kt:89)
                     E      at com.android.systemui.media.MediaDataManager$loadMediaData$1.run(MediaDataManager.kt:241)
                     E      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
                     E      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                     E      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
                     E      at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:67)
                     E  Caused by: android.os.RemoteException: Remote stack trace:
                     E      at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.getContentProviderImpl(ActivityManagerService.java:7155)
                     E      at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.getContentProvider(ActivityManagerService.java:7594)
                     E      at android.app.IActivityManager$Stub.onTransact(IActivityManager.java:2381)
                     E      at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.onTransact(ActivityManagerService.java:2883)
                     E      at android.os.Binder.execTransactInternal(Binder.java:1159)
```

If I remove the line of the builder that sets the small icon, it works fine (but that makes the notification just a plain notification without the media style).   You'll note the exception is about lack for permission for fetching something from a file provider, but nothing in the notification uses anything like that.

Comment: "nothing in the notification uses anything like that" -- perhaps none of your code does, but it is possible that some of the Jetpack code that you are using does. I am very surprised that `setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_stat)` would trigger this, though. You are sure it is that line, and not `builder.setLargeIcon(icon)`?

Comment: Yes, I am sure.  I suspected build.setLargeIcon myself, but it's definitely builder.setSmallIcon.   But when I remove setSmallIcon, it builds a minimal notification, so it might be that it has little to do with the small icon, and more with the fact that no longer builds the full notification.  On a real device, after about 10 seconds, the device reboots.

Comment: Another thing to note, my app doesn't actually crash, the Android UI does.  My app is playing audio from a service, the audio keeps playing until the OS reboots.  On the emulator, the audio keeps playing forever.

Comment: If I don't call setStyle (so its not a MediaStyle Notification any more), it works (with the the small icon set).  So it's definitely not the small icon, but something to do with building the media style notification.

Comment: What version of `androidx.media:media` are you pulling in? That is where you should be getting `NotificationCompat.MediaStyle` from. The current version is 1.2.0, and I do not see where it might be using a `Uri` from `FileProvider`: https://androidx.tech/artifacts/media/media/1.2.0-source/androidx/media/app/NotificationCompat.java.html

Comment: androidx.media:media is 1.2.0.  I made sure everything was up to date yesterday.

Comment: How thoroughly bizarre. Issues with `FileProvider` for notifications have been around for years. I wrote about this [four years ago](https://commonsware.com/blog/2016/09/07/notifications-sounds-android-7p0-aggravation.html), there in the context of providing ringtones. AFAIK, the issue is unsolvable without framework changes. So, I am stunned that the Jetpack team tried using `FileProvider`. You might consider creating a small project that reproduces the problem, then file a bug report.

Comment: @CommonsWare Thank you for all your help.  I agree, it's absolutely bizarre.  I'll see if I can write up a small sample to show the issue.  Seems like there must be two bugs here.  One that Jetpack didn't do the right thing with the FileProvider, and another that crashed the Android UI when it was missing. The behavior when this bug happens, you just have to see to believe it. Its awful.

Comment: If you think of it, post a link to your issue here -- I'd like to take a peek at it.

Comment: @CommonsWare. See below, I found the cause, and file a bug.

Answer (score 1):

I found the issue.   Since this is a MediaStyle, we set the MediaSession, the session has access to the MediaMetadataCompat items.   For building those items, we have:

```
                    val builder = MediaMetadataCompat.Builder()
                        .putString(MediaMetadataCompat.METADATA_KEY_TITLE, doc.title)
                        .putString(MediaMetadataCompat.METADATA_KEY_AUTHOR, doc.author ?: "Unknown")
                        .putString(MediaMetadataCompat.METADATA_KEY_MEDIA_ID, doc.documentId)
                        .putString(MediaMetadataCompat.METADATA_KEY_ALBUM, folders.firstOrNull { it.folderId == doc.folderId }?.folderName)
                        .putString(MediaMetadataCompat.METADATA_KEY_GENRE, sourceType?.name ?: "Unknown") // We don't have Genre info, we'll use for the sourceType
                        .putLong(METADATA_KEY_UAMP_FLAGS, MediaBrowserCompat.MediaItem.FLAG_PLAYABLE.toLong())
                if (originalDocumentType != null) {
                    // We don't have a disc no, so
                    builder.putLong(MediaMetadataCompat.METADATA_KEY_DISC_NUMBER, originalDocumentType.ordinal.toLong())
                }
                // we'll use it doc type.

                if (icon != null) {
                    builder.putString(MediaMetadataCompat.METADATA_KEY_DISPLAY_ICON_URI, icon.toString())
                }
```

Its that last line that sets Icon uri.  That needs permission.
adding this right above that line

```
                        context.grantUriPermission("com.android.systemui", icon, Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION)
```

Now the app runs correctly.  But the fact that is causing the Android UI to crash because that permission was missing is still a bug.  I'd expect to fail to show the icon or even crash the app, but certainly not to crash Android itself.

Comment: I filed android bug here: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/170240577

Comment: Just note that there is no guarantee that this `com.android.systemui` hack will work on all devices. It probably works on most of them, but given a sufficiently-aggressive manufacturer, the notification process might be in a different package. But, I'm glad that you figured out the source of the problem!

Answer (score 0):

This bug is still an issue unfortunately. I had the exact issue, with the notification blowing up the phone and your solution

> > context.grantUriPermission( "com.android.systemui", it.toUri(), Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION)

works so thanks! Seems specific to android 11.

I too had to add this in within the media mappers of an audio app Im working on.